# Alternatives for java npapi pluggin

Tags: javascript, java, plugins, npapi

Chrome, and now Firefox have now phased out NPAPI plugins.  What is a viable solution to the NPAPI depreciation? I support a java based applet that will no longer run in major browsers.  I need an alternative that allows for memory and CPU intensive computations on very large multidimensional arrays and gives me access to the clients filesystem.  Computations need to be displayed to the user through various graphs.  (I currently use J-Free chart for this).  I am unfamiliar with JavaScript.  Will it fulfill all my needs? If not, what else can run such an application in browser? Will I be stuck asking the user to download an executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try GWT http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html . It's google's library that transforms Java code to compatible javascript one (of course you need to learn some new functionality) . This is what i have used in similar situations and i am quite happy with result

Comment: That's pretty amazing!

Comment: emscripten will compile C++ in a similar(ish) way